# Chrome Apps in Login Items fail to start

Tags: google-chrome, login-items

I have a [Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nutrislice-digital-signag/ngejnehjmhmabhmmncljhbhopfhlaine) (packaged app, installed from Chrome App Store) that I want to start up upon login on my Mac (Mavericks).  I add the item to login items under my User in the Accounts area of Sys. Pref., but it (or any Chrome app) fails to start.  The app is located in Users > me > Applications > Chrome Apps. Any ideas why Chrome Apps won't work as login items? Is there something else I can do to get it to automatically start up?

Comment: I'm sure you have to launch Chrome, then tell that to launch the app

Comment: Not sure how that works